# Unicity of a model

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $K$ be a local field, of integer $\mathcal{O}$ and uniformizer $\pi$. Take $\varphi:\mathbb{P}^1_K\to\mathbb{P}^1_K$ a finite morphism and $f\in K(t)$ its associated rationnal function. I'm seeking for model of $\varphi$ in $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathcal{O}$ that is a morphism $\Phi:\mathbb{P}^1_\mathcal{O}\to\mathbb{P}^1_\mathcal{O}$ with $\varphi$ the extention of scalar of $\Phi$ to $K$ that is $\varphi=\Phi\times_\mathcal{O}\text{Id}_K$ ie the following diagram commute,
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{P}^1_K @>{\varphi}>> \mathbb{P}^1_K\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\mathbb{P}^1_\mathcal{O} @>{\Phi}>> \mathbb{P}^1_\mathcal{O}
\end{CD}
It is important for me that this model exists and is unique. I fear to make an huge mistake but for me this is the case.

**Question**: is it true that $\Phi$ always exists and is unique?

My proof:

-Existence: because of the factorality of $\mathcal{O}$ it is always possible to write $f=\pi^k P/Q$ with $P$ and $Q$ elements of $\mathcal{O}[t]$ coprimes. Taking $k\geqslant0$ then $\pi^k P$ and $Q$ are coprime in $\mathcal{O}[t]$. With $t=X/Y$ one has $P(t)/Q(t)=A(X,Y)/B(X,Y)$ with $A,B\in\mathcal{O}[X,Y]_d$ and the fact that $P$ and $Q$ are coprimes induces that $A$ and $B$ are coprimes in $\mathcal{O}[X,Y]$ so $\pi^k A$ and $B$ are global section of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1_\mathcal{O}}(d)$ which generating it so by standard description of morphisms to $\mathbb{P}^n$ (for example Hartshorne II.7.1(b)) we get $\Phi:\mathbb{P}^1_\mathcal{O}\to\mathbb{P}^1_\mathcal{O}$ and it seems clear that this is a model for $\varphi$

-Unicity: composing $\varphi$ with canonical $\gamma:\mathbb{P}^1_K\to\mathbb{P}^1_\mathcal{O}$ and keeping in mind and $\mathbb{P}^1_K\subseteq\mathbb{P}^1_\mathcal{O}$ (it is the generic fiber)  one can reinterpret the model $\Phi$ as extension of $\gamma\circ\varphi$ to the whole $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathcal{O}$. But the generic fiber $\mathbb{P}^1_K$ is dense in $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathcal{O}$ so such extension must be unique.

**Question**: is that proof correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existence of $\Phi$ is equivalent to the good reduction of $\phi$, and not all rational maps have good reduction. In the case it exists it is unique.

The mistake you made is assuming that $P$ and $Q$ are coprime. For example, consider $(t^2 + \pi)/(t+\pi)$ for $\pi$ a uniformizer. The ideal they generate is $(\pi,t) \neq (1)$.

Also, even in the case where you do not run into the problem above, you should not say that $A$ and $B$ are coprime in $\mathcal O[X,Y]$; they are homogeneous so they will never be coprime unless they are constant. What you want to be true is that the only homogeneous prime containing them is the irrelevant ideal. If you homogenize the above example, you will see that the problem prime is $(\pi Y, X)$.

Comment: For my first mistake: my mistake was to think that coprime elements always generating the whole ring ie coprimes elements generate coprime ideals. It is wrong "because" $\mathcal{O}[X,Y]$ is only UFD and is not a PID. Here $P$ and $Q$ are coprimes in the sense of factorial ring but the not generating the while ring $\mathcal{O}[X,Y]$.

Comment: Yes exactly right

Comment: For me the good reduction of $\phi$ was that there exists automorphisms $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of $\mathbb{P}^1_K$ such that $\psi=\alpha\circ\phi\circ\beta$ has a model $\Psi$. I don't see why the existence $\Psi$ should imply the existence of a model $\Phi$ for $\phi$ (we should for that lifting the automorphism $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to automoprhisms of $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathcal{O}$ and I don't see how to make that). Is my definition false?

Comment: Definitions are neither true nor false. Some people say that a map has "good reduction" if it is conjugate to a rational map that has what I call good reduction (the property that the morphism extends to $\mathbb P_{\mathcal O}$). You are right that if $\psi$ has good reduction (my definition) then its conjugate does not necessarily have good reduction (for my definition).

Comment: Do you have any good reference over this subject? The classicals of algebraic geometry explain models of schemes but no models of morphisms...